# Como selecionar os elementos irmãos?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando modificar uma configuração de uma div irmã, porém estou com dificuldades em encontrar 
o seletor correto para utilizar, sei que o html trabalha como uma arvore e, geralmente quando preciso selecionar
um elemento superior utilizo o `parent()` e quando se trata de um inferior utilizo o `find()`.

Como seria  para selecionar um de mesmo nível?

Comment: Poste a estrutura que está para ser mais fácil lhe ajudar. Aproveite e faça um [tour] e entenda melhor como o site funciona.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode utilizar `siblings` como o priprio nome diz "irmãos".

**Exemplo:**

```js
$('#foo').click(function() {
  var t = $(this).siblings(); // Vai pegar todos os irmãos.
  var t2 = $(this).siblings('#bar'); // Vai pegar apenas o irmão com id correspondente.
  var t3 = $(this).siblings('.bar'); // Vai pegar todos irmãos com as classes correspondente.
  console.log(t);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">FOO</div>
<div id="bar" class="bar">BAR</div>
<div id="bar2" class="bar">BAR2</div>
```

caso você queria apenas pegar o próximo irmão, você poderá utilizar também o `next()`.

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra forma além da resposta do [@Gabriel Rodrigues](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116448/20615) seria utilizar o `.parent()` e o `.find()` para selecionar qual deseja.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btn').click(function(){
    var irma = $(this).parent().find('#irma').html();
    console.log(irma);
    $('#resultado').html(irma);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="irmao">
    eu sou o irmão
  </div>
  <div id="irma">
    eu sou a irmã
  </div>
  <button id="btn">
    Clica aqui
  </button>
  <p id="resultado"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Este cenário só funciona se você tem IDs para seus elementos. Num cenários mais comum, onde se procura por tags e/ou classes, dessa forma você pegaria os elementos irmãos + o próprio elemento.

Comment: @FReNeTiC Concordo com você. Porém eu [pedi mais explicações](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116446/como-selecionar-os-elementos-irm%C3%A3os/116450#comment242926_116446) sobre o problema em específico, e como não obtive eu resolvi apenas postar essa outra forma.

Comment: Lembrando também que o `.parent()` e o `.find()` não funcionam apenas com IDs dos elementos, eu que estou usando desta forma para demonstração.